# How to get URL of REST endpoint?

Tags: java, rest, wildfly-10

Can someone explain why this URL returns 404?

`http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/hat`

How should I be passing this so the parameter `hat` is passed in and see `Hello hat!` on the output

HelloService.java

```
package com.sentiment360.helloworld;

public class HelloService {

    String createHelloMessage(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.sentiment360.helloworld;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 * A simple REST service which is able to say hello to someone using HelloService Please take a look at the web.xml where JAX-RS
 * is enabled
 *
 * @author gbrey@redhat.com
 *
 */

@Path("/")
public class HelloWorld {
    @Inject
    HelloService helloService;

    @GET
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public String getHelloWorldJSON() {
        return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "\"}";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    public String getHelloWorldXML() {
        return "<xml><result>" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "</result></xml>";
    }

}
```

JAXActivator.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.sentiment360.helloworld;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 * JAXActivator is an arbitrary name, what is important is that javax.ws.rs.core.Application is extended
 * and the @ApplicationPath annotation is used with a "rest" path.  Without this the rest routes linked to
 * from index.html would not be found.
 */
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JAXActivator extends Application {
    // Left empty intentionally
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

My directory structure:

[image: my directory structure]

Comment: ...Why wouldn't it?  You haven't mentioned that you're deploying to the `HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT` context, and there's no route that I can see that ends in `/hat`.

Comment: My apologies, I am deploying through a WildFly server, and the `hat` is the text being sent to the hellloworld

Comment: No it's not.  That's part of the path.  It's not a query parameter, and it's not part of a POST payload.

Comment: ooh, it sounds like I am not setting the path correctly. How should I be passing in the parameter through the URL so the REST api receives it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are using does not match your configuration.

Given your configuration you have 2 possible resources to request:

1. http://your_server/rest/json
2. http://your_server/rest/xml

which basically differ in the produced contenttype.

**Edit:** Ok, i will post necessary changes so that you have **exactly** the output you asked for given the **exact** query you wanted to use:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    @Inject
    HelloService helloService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{helloSuffix}")
    public String getHello(@PathParam("helloSuffix") String helloSuffix) {
        return helloService.createHelloMessage(helloSuffix);
    }
}
```

JAXActivator.java
    ...

```
@ApplicationPath("HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest")
public class JAXActivator extends Application {
}
```

Comment: so I should be using the URL: `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/json/hat`? This returns `Not Found`

Comment: No, try - http://your_server/rest/json?parameterName=hat is the type of URL you should have, but your code will need to handle for query parameters

Comment: @Rilcon42 what you say does not match your configuration. You are not configuring any resource that does any dynamic output based on your request (it's impossible to have a Hello hat!). Look at your HelloWorld.java ; both resources just print a hardcoded "Hello World". If you want that dynamic stuff you are describing, I suggest you to look at jaxrs documentation (Path annotation and PathParam).

Comment: @Rilcon42 added an edit on my answer with the needed changes to accomplish what you requested.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try to match your request URI:

> http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/hat

- The context root is `HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT`, just the name of the WAR file as you haven't overridden it.
- The path to your REST resources is configured as `rest` in your Application subclass (`JAXActivator`). So until this point everything is correct.
- The next part in the URI is the `hat`. But this path is not mapped to any method in your resource class; thus producing the `404` exception. So the valid mappings to your resource class are either:

  `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/json`, or

  `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/xml`

It seems you want also to send a parameter to your REST methods:

- `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/json/hat` or
- `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/xml/hat`

depending on whether you want JSON or XML response. To be able to do this you have to modify your REST methods as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("/json/{p}")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public String getHelloWorldJSON(@PathParam("p") String param) {
    return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage(param) + "\"}";
}

@GET
@Path("/xml/{p}")
@Produces({ "application/xml" })
public String getHelloWorldXML(@PathParam("p") String param) {
    return "<xml><result>" + helloService.createHelloMessage(param) + "</result></xml>";
}
```

Here is the definition of `@PathParam` as stated in the JAX-RS 2.0 specification:

> Specifies that the value of a *method parameter*, class field, or bean property is to be extracted from a URI query parameter. The value of the annotation identifies the name of a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your endpoints like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/rest/{name}")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getHelloWorldJSON(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage(name) + "\"}";
}

@GET
@Path("/rest/{name}")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getHelloWorldJSON(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return "<xml><result>" + helloService.createHelloMessage(name) + "</result></xml>";
}
```

The @Consumes is the right way to change from json and xml input.
The @Path("rest/{name}") is doing the binding of this endpoint to /rest/something, and the @PathParam("name") is binding the variable path value to the variable name

This will work if your server is correctly deployed in http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT